# Converting a noughts and crosses game onto an 4 x 4 grid

Tags: python

I keep on running into list index errors within my sub routine that decides when there is a winner and I'm not sure what to do, I a not fussed with finding the diagonal winning option though, If more info is needed just ask. Here is my original code that was on the 3 x 3 grid:

```
Board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]


def CheckXOr0HasWon(Board):
    XOrOHasWon = False
    for Column in range(1,4):
        if (Board[Column][1] == Board[Column][2]) and (Board[Column][2] == Board[Column][3]) and 
(Board[Column][2] != ' '):
            XOrOHasWon = True
    for Row in range(1,4):
        if (Board[1][Row] == Board[2][Row]) and (Board[2][Row] == Board[3][Row]) and (Board[2][Row] != ' '):
            XOrOHasWon = True
    if (Board[1][1] == Board[2][2]) and (Board[2][2] == Board[3][3]) and (Board[2][2] != ' '):
        XOrOHasWon = True
    if (Board[3][1] == Board[2][2]) and (Board[2][2] == Board[1][3]) and (Board[2][2] != ' '):
        XOrOHasWon = True
    return XOrOHasWon
```

And here is the what i have done for the 4 x 4 grid:

```
Board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]

def CheckXOr0HasWon(Board):
    XOrOHasWon = False
    for Column in range(1,5):
        if (Board[Column][1] == Board[Column][2]) and (Board[Column][2] == Board[Column][3]) and 
(Board[Column][3] == Board[Column][4]) and (Board[Column][2][3] != ' '):
            XOrOHasWon = True
    for Row in range(1,5):
        if (Board[1][Row] == Board[2][Row]) and (Board[2][Row] == Board[3][Row]) and (Board[3][Row] == Board[4][Row]) and (Board[2][3][Row] != ' '):
            XOrOHasWon = True
    if (Board[1][1] == Board[2][2]) and (Board[2][2] == Board[3][3]) and (Board[2][2] != ' '):
    XOrOHasWon = True
    if (Board[3][1] == Board[2][2]) and (Board[2][2] == Board[1][3]) and (Board[2][2] != ' '):
        XOrOHasWon = True
    return XOrOHasWon
```

Comment: Please provide the error traceback.

Comment: lin CheckXOr0HasWon
    if (Board[Column][1] == Board[Column][2]) and (Board[Column][2] == Board[Column][3]) and (Board[Column][3] == Board[Column][4]) and (Board[Column][2][3] != ' '):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Oh, I see: Board[4] is going to be out of range, because indexing starts with zero in Python.

Comment: ahh i see, so should i be changing the range to range(0,4) and then making changing it to Board[3] and respectively for the other values and also adding a new row in the board.?